# Automating Sign-up via POST requests

Tags: python, post, python-requests

Not quite sure where I am going wrong. I am trying to get a better knowledge using POST requests and I am trying to automate the sign up for a specific webpage. I believe I am going wrong because I am quite unsure on how to update the 'X-XSRF-TOKEN' every time as it is not stored in a cookie.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import requests
import json
import time
import random
import decimal
from fake_useragent import UserAgent





GET_URL = 'https://accounts.epicgames.com/register/doCustomRegister'

POST_URL = 'https://accounts.epicgames.com/register/doCustomRegister?productName=fortnite'




#########################################
NAME = 'someName'
LAST_NAME = 'someLastName'
DISPLAY_NAME = 'someDisplayName'
EMAIL = 'someEmail@gmail.com'
PASSWORD = 'somePassword'
#########################################



USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.62 Safari/537.36'





session = requests.Session()

session.headers = {'user_agent' : USER_AGENT}

session.headers.update({'Referer' : GET_URL})

get = session.get(GET_URL)



session.headers.update({'user_agent': USER_AGENT})


form_data = {
'X-XSRF-TOKEN' : '',

'X-XSRF-URI' : '/register/doRegister',

'fromForm' : 'yes',

'location' : '/location',

'authType' : '',

'client_id' : '',

'redirectUrl' : 'https://www.epicgames.com/fortnite/register',

'country' : 'US',

'name' : NAME,

'lastName' : LAST_NAME,

'displayName' : DISPLAY_NAME,

'email' : EMAIL,

'password' : PASSWORD,

'termsAgree' : 'yes', 

'register' : 'Create Account',

'productName' : 'fortnite'
}



post = session.post(POST_URL, data=form_data, allow_redirects=True)
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what you are trying to accomplish from your question. Can you be more specific as to what you are trying to do?

Comment: Trying to send a request to sign up on a webpage using the given form data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The token is in the html source:

```
input type="hidden" name="X-XSRF-TOKEN" value="26660efc-6d90-4ef6-a717-fb9cfed99bad" id="X-XSRF-TOKEN"
```

You can use BeautifulSoup to parse the html and get the token:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
url = 'https://accounts.epicgames.com/register/doCustomRegister?productName=fortnite'
resp = requests.get(url)
soup = BS(resp.text, 'lxml')
token = soup.select_one('input[id="X-XSRF-TOKEN"]')['value']
print(token)
```

Comment: This worked! However now I am trying to get the "client_id", and when I follow the same logic above (changing input=, to name=),  I get a TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: I can't see a `client_id` parameter in the page or in the cookies.